# R studio creating "Extra" factor on categorial variables

Tags: r, statistics

Im still pretty new to R, so please bear over with me here. When I load my dataset into R studio, it creates a factor with 4 levels, on a categorial variable with the values "High", "Medium and "Low". shouldn't this only be a factor with 3 levels?
So when the variable (vector) budget.level in my dataset has the following values:

```
Budget.level <- c("High","Medium","low")

levels(Budget.level)
```

The output I get is this
[image]
[image]

Why do I get this extra empty level?
Please tell me if you need more information.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any missing/NULL values?  What's the output from `unique(mvc_new$Budget.level)`?

Comment: In the screen shot you shared there are 4 levels: "", "High", "Low", "Medium". That empty string is considered a level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure empty strings turn into NA. This depends entirely on which function or method you use to load the data.

`read.table` uses `na.strings = "NA"` for example. you could change that to use `""` instead.

`read_xlsx` uses `na = ""` which would work as a default for you.

You can also manually clean this up afterwards:

```
mvc_new$Budget.level[ mvc_new$Budget.level %in% "" ] <- NA
mvc_new$Budget.level <- factor( mvc_new$Budget.level )
```

Comment: Thanks! The `Na.strings = ""` fixed it.